# How to i make a list of randomized objects, from a list of objects

Tags: python, list

I have defined a class, and made a list of objects with parameters from said class, and sorted the list in ascending order, based on one of the parameters.

```
import random 

class Elev:
    def __init__(self, navn, nivaa, braakete):
        self.navn = navn
        self.nivaa = nivaa
        self.braakte = braakete

    def __str__(self):
        return self.navn + "," + str(self.nivaa)

KL = [Elev("Bruh", 4, 6), Elev("Famsquad", 1, 6), Elev("Alex", 6, 1), Elev("Albania", 3, 4), Elev("Aron", 2, 6), Elev("Adrian", 4, 3), Elev("Bruh", 5, 1), Elev("Sakka", 1, 3), Elev("A", 5, 2), Elev("B", 1, 6), Elev("C", 4,4), Elev("D", 5, 1), Elev("E", 2, 5), Elev("F", 4,2), Elev("H", 4, 2)]

KL.sort(key = lambda Elev:Elev.nivaa, reverse = True)
```

I then want to split the list up and create pairs, where the lowermost and the uppermost objects are paired together, but I want it to be sort of random. Meaning that I want a list of pairs, where highest and lowest objects are paired together, but it doesn't have to be the highest and the lowest value - it can also be the lowest and the second-highest value together. To do this I have created a boundary for how "low" a value has to be before it has to be sorted into a list;

```
def limit():
    if (int(len(KL)*0.2)%2) == 0:
        return int(len(KL)*0.2)
    else:
        return int(len(KL)*0.2)+1
```

(The reason for the "elif"function, is because I want to return an even number.)
The `limit()` I just returned is the uppermost and lowermost index-value of the list of objects: `KL`. From this `limit()` I want to create random pairs of the objects I have created the limit for:

```
list(zip(KL[(random.shuffle(:grense())]), reversed(KL[random.shuffle(grense():])))
```

I then get the errormessage: `TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 2` and ``ìnvalid syntax```
Any ideas on how I can fix this problem, or simplify?

I am sorry to anyone reading this, because it is a messy explanation, but I couldn't make it any simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gr = limit()
low = KL[:gr]
high = KL[-gr:]
random.shuffle(low)
random.shuffle(high)
list( zip( low , high ) )
```

random.shuffle shuffles a list in place and returns None. The error raised is due to parenthesis problem, also the returned value from shuffle can't be used as a list index as it's None